# Are there any cables available to port HDMI to Displayport (And possibly carry audio?)

Tags: audio, hdmi, displayport

I would like to use an HDMI output device with a DisplayPort monitor. My main issue is getting audio.. HDMI to DVI doesn't support audio. Are there any cables that do HDMI to Displayport and support audio?

Comment: One cannot legally create an "HDMI-to-DisplayPort cable" or a "DisplayPort-to-HDMI cable". Such a thing would *have* to be an [adapter](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2388289,00.asp). To use the name "HDMI" in connection with a product requires it to pass HDMI compliance testing, and there is no compliance test for such a cable.

Comment: ok... but outside of the legality, then, is it possible? and would there be able to be approved cables too?

Comment: Less than 2% of Monitors do not have HDMI, but bassically all [1] have a sperate audio-in. I would recommend to use a cable for mute-video and an seperate one for Audio.

[1] https://geizhals.eu/?cmp=1617137&cmp=1539883&cmp=1617127&cmp=1716880&cmp=1539821&cmp=1716381&cmp=1441388&cmp=1441392&cmp=1128075&cmp=1199579&cmp=1199602&cmp=772957&active=0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update 2022:** Not sure if the answer below is still up to date. As pointed out in the comments, there is a [product](https://www.club-3d.com/de/detail/2465/displayport_1.4_auf_hdmi_2.0b_hdr_kabel_stecker-stecker_2_meter/) (DisplayPort™ 1.4 auf HDMI™ 2.0b HDR Kabel by Club 3D), which claims that it does the job.

Short answer: <s>No.</s> **Update:** maybe...?

Long answer:

At least at  [displayport.org](http://www.displayport.org/faq/) it writes explicitly that there is no such device. Note that there are several devices for the other direction (DisplayPort device/output, HDMI monitor/input), but they do not work the other way around. I personally tried to connect my laptop (HDMI) with a monitor (DisplayPort) using [this cable](http://www.delock.de/produkte/G_82586/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en). There was simply no image.

Anyhow, I don't think that it's technically impossible to build such an adapter. I am curious myself why you can't buy such a device and if the information at   [displayport.org](http://www.displayport.org/faq/) is actually (still?) correct.

Comment: I could not find the part at displayport.org which supports that "there is no such a device". Maybe it is there but it would be helpful if you could quote the specific part so that we can find it there if we want. The reason I was checking what they say is that while there is no *cable* that will do the conversion, there appear to be devices that can convert the HDMI signal coming out of a source, to a DP signal that a DP monitor can accept.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I should have pasted the quoted from beginning. I don't which part I read which led me to believe that there is no such device. Note that I was searching for such a thing 2,5 years ago, back then I couldn't find any.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbWJkVj8Xgw It's possible

Comment: What is your monitor resolution? Is it below 1920x1200@60Hz? Did you claim warranty? Maybe try https://www.club-3d.com/de/detail/2465/displayport_1.4_auf_hdmi_2.0b_hdr_kabel_stecker-stecker_2_meter/

Comment: @JoKalliauer seems as if the device you linked does the job, although the image with the arrow on the product package seems to be very misleading (the arrow points the other direction). I don't remember which monitor I tried in 2013, nor did I claim warranty since nobody claimed that this would work.

Comment: @lumbric You are right, I think for HDMI to DP you should use: https://www.lindy.de/?websale8=ld0101.ld011101&pi=38289&ci=272

Answer (score 2):

you can use two adapters, but you won't be able to carry the audio. The common denominator would be DVI. You will need an HDMI to DVI adaptor and a DisplayPort to DVI adaptor. I happen to have both so that's what I'm using.
I don't need to pass the audio. I guess that can be done through other avenues.
Sorry if that doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

This question has become relevant again, while considering how to connect a Thunderbolt 3/USB-C port on a 2016 MacBook Pro to an older monitor with a DisplayPort but no HDMI. One option would be to use a Thunderbolt 3/USB-C to HDMI adapter (which I need anyway for an HDMI monitor) with an HDMI to DisplayPort cable, like the OP was looking for, if they existed.

The best explanation about why such cables don't exist that I could find is in a 2013 post here: http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/hdmi-to-dp-adapter-do-they-exist.734997/ – see the "Short answer: Not worth the hassle" by kent1146.

Active devices that are somewhat less expensive than the example in that post and get power from a USB port now exist; for example, see [https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-Plated-DisplayPort-Converter/dp/B00JQORLCG/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JQORLCG), with links to others further down the page.

Comment: In case the referenced post at Notebook Review disappears, the crux of it is that going from HDMI to DisplayPort requires a $70-$100 active device that requires power, and if your monitor has DVI, just get an HDMI to DVI cable instead for much less money.

Answer (score 0):

What @Flagbase09 stated is wrong: there are HDMI to DVI cables, but there are no DVI to DP cables, the ones that exist only convert from DP to DVI.

I have found one model from FOINNEX trademark that it says it converts from HDMI to DP. I will give it a try once it arrives at me. It is available to purchase online on Amazon, Aliexpress, etc.

[FOINNEX cable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2jjy.png)

Comment: There absolutely are DisplayPort to HDMI adapters.  I also have HDMI to DisplayPort (powered by USB) adapters.  This answer was mistakenly submitted as answer instead of a comment to the stated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **Yes**

Transfer of audio and video signals :

Male-HDMI  to Male-Displayport (up to 2560×1440@60Hz):

- [Club3D-2m](https://www.club-3d.com/de/detail/2465/displayport_1.4_auf_hdmi_2.0b_hdr_kabel_stecker-stecker_2_meter/), [Club3D-3m](https://www.club-3d.com/de/detail/2365/displayport_1.2_kabel_auf_aktiven_hdmi_2.0_uhd_4k60hz_adapter_stecker-stecker_3m/)
- [2m-DeLock](https://www.delock.com/produkt/85317/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en), [3m-DeLock](https://www.delock.com/produkt/85318/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en), [5m-DeLock](https://www.delock.com/produkt/85319/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en)

Male-HDMI to Female-Displayport with Audio:

- [Lindy_old](https://www.lindy.de/Konverter-HDMI-auf-DisplayPort-bis-UHD-4K-30-Hz-USB-powered.htm?websale8=ld0101.ld011101&pi=38147&ci=10), [Lindy_new](https://www.lindy.de/?websale8=ld0101.ld011101&pi=38289&ci=272)
- [DeLock](https://www.delock.de/produkt/63206/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en), [DeLock with USB-A](https://www.delock.de/produkt/62667/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en),[DeLock with USB-A](https://www.delock.de/produkt/62496/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en), [DeLock with USB-A](https://www.delock.de/produkt/62959/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en)

Male-Displayport to Female-HDMI with Audio:

- [Axagon](https://www.axagon.eu/de/produkty/rvd-hi)
- [Lindy](https://www.lindy.de/DisplayPort-an-HDMI-4K-Adapterkabel-passiv.htm?websale8=ld0101.ld011101&pi=41718&ci=10) [Lindy](https://www.lindy.de/DisplayPort-1-4-auf-HDMI-8K-Konverter-aktiv.htm?websale8=ld0101.ld011101&pi=41094&ci=20) [Lindy](https://www.lindy.de/HDMI-18G-auf-DisplayPort-1-2-Konverter.htm?websale8=ld0101.ld011101&pi=38303)
- [Club3D](https://www.club-3d.com/de/detail/2442/)
- [StarTech](https://www.startech.com/de-de/audio-video-products/dp2hd4kadap), [StarTech](https://www.startech.com/de-de/audio-video-products/dp2hd4k60s)
- [DeLock](https://www.delock.de/produkt/65573/merkmale.html?setLanguage=de) [DeLock](https://www.delock.de/produkt/62607/merkmale.html?setLanguage=de) [DeLock](https://www.delock.de/produkt/65580/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en) [DeLock](https://www.delock.de/produkt/62608/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en), [DeLock](https://www.delock.de/produkt/65207/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en) [DeLock](https://www.delock.de/produkt/65207/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en), [DeLock](https://www.delock.de/produkt/62902/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en)

If you need more video-bandwidth, you need to search deeper.

More options can be found found at:

- https://geizhals.eu/?cat=kabeladapt&xf=5839_HDMI%7E5842_oDP
- https://geizhals.eu/?cat=kabeladapt&xf=5839_HDMI%7E5839_oDP
- https://geizhals.eu/?cat=kabeladapt&xf=5839_oDP%7E5842_HDMI

Comment: Check again: Many of the cables/adapters you link are in fact not HDMI → DP but the other way around.

Comment: That's true, but e.g. https://www.lindy.de/?websale8=ld0101.ld011101&pi=38289&ci=272 converts HDMI -> DP. So the short answer is still true

Comment: Sure it is. However, this question is specifically about HDMI → DisplayPort. Any other content will simply confuse or mislead casual readers. Furthermore, many products are incorrectly classified. For example, the first two Club3D devices are actually DP → HDMI.

Answer (score -1):

There are DisplayPort to HDMI adapters - here's an example - http://www.cdw.com/shop/products/StarTech.com-DisplayPort-to-HDMI-Video-Adapter-Converter-video-audio-ad/1690001.aspx

Comment: will these port the sound through (my monitor has an audio hook-up)

Comment: I believe it should, but I do not have any firsthand experience.  I'll defer to someone who's tried it.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The adapter works only the other way around. From the description: "Connect your HDMI monitor or HDTV to a DisplayPort equipped computer. The DP2HDMIADAP DisplayPort to HDMI Adapter provides a DisplayPort male and HDMI female connector, allowing you to keep your existing (HDMI) display while using a DisplayPort video card/source."