# Achieving 2560x1080 Resolution Using DVI Source and HDMI Endpoint

Tags: hdmi, dvi

Ok, I'll sum this up so I can try and get some help here:

- I have an LG 29" UltraWide monitor. The genius that designed it put two HDMI inputs on the back, and that's it.
- I have the GeForce GT 740 4GB GDDR5 in my machine, and it works WONDERFUL... However:

Card:
Mini-HDMI
DVI-I [Dual Link]
DVI-D [Dual Link]

Monitor:
HDMI [Capable of 2650 x 1080]
HDMI [Capable of 2650 x 1080]

Where in the heck does one get a Dual-Link DVI to HDMI adapter or cable? All I need is 6 feet (10 would be better) but I can't seem to find anything. I'm currently using a Mini-HDMI to HDMI cable, and it's obviously not dual link capable, so I've got black bars on the left and right (just 1920x1080).

I've got an active Mini-Displayport to HDMI adapter that I'm using with a Mac Mini 2012, and it outputs the glorious 2560x1080 -- the GT 740 doesn't have display port anywhere, so that's not an option. :\

Comment: Please see: http://superuser.com/questions/332099/does-a-hdmi-to-dvi-dual-link-adapter-exist-i-dont-care-about-the-price Almost your case, just the other direction, but you'll probably still need an active adapter

Comment: Thanks! There was a comment mushed into the middle there that said the following:
2560x1600 @ 35Hz works because it's slow enough for single link DVI (pixel clock is less than 165 MHz). Anything faster for DVI such as 2560x1600 @ 60Hz requires dual link DVI which these HDMI adapters do not support. HDMI is single link but allows for pixel clocks up to 340 MHz (HDMI 1.3 or greater). 

So, I'm not gaming or anything, so didn't care for 60Hz or not -- I hooked up a normal DVI cable (single link) to a DVI to HDMI adapter (nothing special about it) and was able to choose 2560x1080!

Thanks!

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

2560x1600 @ 35Hz works because it's slow enough for single link DVI (pixel clock is less than 165 MHz). Anything faster for DVI such as 2560x1600 @ 60Hz requires dual link DVI which these HDMI adapters do not support.

HDMI is single link but allows for pixel clocks up to 340 MHz (HDMI 1.3 or greater). So, I'm not gaming or anything, so didn't care for 60Hz or not --

**In short**: I hooked up a normal DVI cable (single link) to a DVI to HDMI adapter (nothing special about it) and was able to choose 2560x1080!